# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme and appeared the following parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/storage/9/ad/41/hunamarcenaria1/public_html/wp-content/themes/blink/page.php on line 1

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'includes/page-title' ); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="centered-wrapper">
    <section class="percent-page> 
        <?php echo $deliciousmt:delicious_sidebar_position($post->ID); ?>
        <article id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="begin-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </article>
        <?php   
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;      
        ?>          
        <div class="double-space"></div>
    </section>      
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>             
<?php
    global $dt_sidebar_pos;
    if(($dt_sidebar_pos === 'sidebar-right') || ($dt_sidebar_pos === 'sidebar-left'))
        get_sidebar();      
 ?>
</div><!--end centered-wrapper-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I 'm not a programmer , I'm trying to solve the problem but I have no idea what to do . If anyone can help me it would be amazing !

Comment: Carriage returns are *really* useful for making code readable.  And it will be *a lot* easier for you to spot errors in your code if it's designed to be read by humans.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
<?php echo $deliciousmt:delicious_sidebar_position($post->ID); ?>  
                       ^
```

Use `.` operator

```
<?php echo $deliciousmt." : ".delicious_sidebar_position($post->ID); ?>
```

Next correction

```
<section class="percent-page>
```

missing closing `"` for class

```
<section class="percent-page">
                            ^
```